# Can't retrieve links inside Frame

Tags: autoit

I am trying to use AutoIt to retrieve some data from this website:

http://www.acgme.org/adspublic/default.asp

Unfortunately, the page uses frames and I'm having trouble navigating to the page where the data is.

The link is "Accredited Programs"

```
#include <IE.au3> 

$URL="http://www.acgme.org/adspublic/"
$MyIExplorer=_IECreate($URL,1,1,1,1)

Local $theFrame = _IEGetObjById($MyIExplorer,"control")
MsgBox(0,"The Frame",$theFrame.src)

Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($theFrame)
MsgBox(0, "Link Count", @extended & " links found")
```

When I run the code above, I am able to populate `$theFrame` with the correct frame object that houses the "Accredited Programs" link, but that's as far as I can get. The `$oLinks` collection comes back empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frames are rather special. Use _IEFrameGetObjByName instead.

```
#include <IE.au3>

$URL="http://www.acgme.org/adspublic/"
$MyIExplorer=_IECreate($URL,1,1,1,1)

Local $theFrame = _IEFrameGetObjByName($MyIExplorer,"control")

Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($theFrame)
MsgBox(0, "Link Count", @extended & " links found")
```

Comment: Thanks @Manadar, I tried `_IEFrameGetObjByName` at one point and couldn't get it to work.  I accredit this to being a AutoIt newbie.  I finally got my code to work by using `_IEFrameGetCollection` instead.  Thanks for your help!