# AutoIt - Click a Link in a iFrame

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, autoit

I am new to using AutoIt.  I have been struggling to click a link in an iframe using Internet Explorer.  I have looked at several ways to do this but have not got anything to work.

So this is probably a simple question.  How do a click a link inside an iFrame using AutoIt?  The link is in frame 8 and the text name is "People".

Could someone please provide a example?

I assume I have to use _IEFrameGetCollection and _IELinkClickByText.  I have also managed to identify the total number of frames on my page being 9 using _IEFrameGetCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume I have to use _IEFrameGetCollection and _IELinkClickByText. I have also managed to identify the total number of frames on my page being 9 using _IEFrameGetCollection.

Precisely. You may want to see this answer first: [Can't retrieve links inside Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982682/autoit-cant-retrieve-links-inside-frame)

Your code will end up something like:

```
#include <IE.au3>

$URL="http://www.acgme.org/adspublic/"
$MyIExplorer=_IECreate($URL,1,1,1,1)

Local $theFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($MyIExplorer, 8)

Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($theFrame)
MsgBox(0, "Link Count", @extended & " links found")
```